# Styling a form where the input fields have implicit labels (wrapped in labels)

Tags: css, forms

Given an html form like this:

```
<form action='/example/' id='example_form' method='POST' name='example_form'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Example form</legend>
    <label for='age'>
      Age
      <input id='age' name='age' tabindex='1' type='text' />
    </label>
    <label for='gender'>
      Gender
      <select id='gender' name='gender' tabindex='2'>
        <option disabled='disabled' id='gender' name='gender' value=''>Choose one:</option>
        <option id='gender_female' name='gender' value='female'>Female</option>
        <option id='gender_male' name='gender' value='male'>Male</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label for='height'>
      Height
      <input id='height' name='height' size='3' tabindex='3' type='text' />
    </label>
    <label for='weight'>
      Weight
      <input id='weight' name='weight' size='4' tabindex='4' type='text' />
    </label>
    <input id='Save' tabindex='5' type='submit' value='Save' />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

How would you style it to get the classic table based layout of label to the left, field to the right, everything aligned vertically? Tables are obviously out of the question. I can't find anything on how to do this with **implicit** labels and just CSS.

If the answer is to *not* wrap the fields then so be it, but I'd prefer if a solution could be found for this as:

1. This is generated html.
2. I keep reading about how using implicit labels improves accessibility.

Any help/pointers/insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some basic stylings to get started

**[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/GPqN4/)**

```
fieldset {width:300px;}
label {display:block;overflow:hidden;line-height:30px;}
label input, label select {float:right;}
input[type=submit] {float:right;width:100px;border:solid 1px;}
```

Comment: I just tried that out and I'm incredibly impressed! I'm not sure if that says more about my knowledge of CSS or yours :D Thanks very much, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Or, depending on what you mean by 'vertically aligned', you could try this.

```
label {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
label > input,
label > select {
    position: absolute;
    left: 70px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDKzk/1/)

or an alternative [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDKzk/1/)

Comment: That's also really impressive. It does make the fields all the same width regardless of the size attribute due to the `width`, but it's really helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I only added the width so that _everything_ is aligned vertically. The second example on jsfiddle shows it without.

Answer (score 1):

CSS will never cease to amaze me. Based on the answer of @magicalex I came up with the following:

```
label {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
label > input,
label > select,
input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
}
```

This manages to do most of what I had in mind, namely a horizontal layout with all the labels aligned to the right and all the fields aligned to the left, even if they were not the same width (which is unavoidable e.g. for iOS date pickers and the like).

However the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh8kzez9/) illustrates the remaining problem of aligning a field if the label is broken into multiple lines (e.g. because of translations). But I guess this can be solved as well.